# View single post from list of posts in certain category Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a script that generates all the posts that have a particular category tag (see below).

```
    <?php 
            function create_slug($string){
                $slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string);
                return $slug;
            }

            $category = strtolower(create_slug(single_cat_title('', false)));
            $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'research-case',
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'posts_per_page' => 6,
                        'category_name' => $category                       
                    );

            query_posts($args); 
        ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <hr /> 

            <article class="item">

              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
              <h3 class="title-news"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
              <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
               <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo __('View details' , 'roots'); ?> &raquo;</a></p>
            </article>

      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
```

However, when I click on a particular post with the link provided by `the_permalink();` method my website throws a 404 error. I believe I need a template file that will pull the content from an individual post. Does anyone know how this is done?

Comment: Ensure your theme has a single.php file, WordPress uses that file to display individual post.

Comment: @Anand I've got a `single.php` file but it still throws the 404 error

Comment: What does the URL produced by `the_permalink` look like?

Comment: http://sitename/case-studies/case-study-title/